# How can I get the cumulant expression from the recursive relation between cumulant and moment?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moments, signal-processing, cumulants

I am reading some paper about high-order statistics https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11004-009-9258-9?LI=true. The paper gives two recursive expressions relating the multivariate cumulants to moments, as shown in first and second attached figures. Also the expressions of cumulants expressed as moments are given directly (i.e. c1,2,3, c1,2,3,4).
[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

I want to derive the expression of multivariate cumulant from the recursive relation. But I am stuck with even the derivation of bivariate cumulant (Figure 3).

[image: Figure 3]

Is there someone familiar with the high-order statistics? Please give me some help to get out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a proof in the paper. Instead, Smith (1995), which was published much earlier, seems to include a different formula for obtaining cumulants from moments in the multivariate setting. In contrast to the method in the paper you have posted, which is one-step, Smith (1995) suggests a two-step method for obtaining multivariate moments. I suggest checking out the paper.

Smith, P. J. (1995). A Recursive Formulation of the Old Problem of Obtaining Moments from Cumulants and Vice Versa. The American Statistician, 49(2), 217–218. doi:10.1080/00031305.1995.10476146